# security error in connectycube video call

Tags: react-native, connectycube

**when i execute this code in reactnative by connecty cube video call :**

```
var calleesIds = [218307,218308]; // User's ids
var sessionType = ConnectyCube.videochat.CallType.VIDEO; // AUDIO is also possible
var additionalOptions = {};

var session = ConnectyCube.videochat.createNewSession(calleesIds, sessionType, additionalOptions);
var mediaParams = {
      audio: true,
      video: false
    };

    session.getUserMedia(mediaParams, function(error, stream) {
    alert('stream'+stream)
    console.log('errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr>>>>>>>  :'+JSON.stringify(error))
    });
```

I give this error:

```
errrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr>>>>>>>  :{"name":"SecurityError","message":"Permission denied."}
```

Comment: what's package you used for that?

Comment: Android or iOS? If android - did you add all required permissions for camera/mic into AndroidManifest file ?

Comment: yes i have permission for recordaudio and camera

Comment: but now i have this error

Comment: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.getUserMedia')

Comment: Please post your package.json and what RN version you use

Answer (score 0):

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Coco",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.8.23",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "connectycube-reactnative": "^1.8.1",
    "fluidbottomnavigation-rn": "^0.1.1",
    "link": "^0.1.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.7.2",
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-animated-swipeout": "^2.0.14",
    "react-native-animated-tabs": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-animation-layout": "0.0.13",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-autogrow-input": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-camera-roll-picker": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-camera-roll-selector": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-custom-radio-group": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-dial-menu": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-easy-tabs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-floating-action": "^1.17.0",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.2.9",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.5",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-input-validator": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-jalali-date-picker": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-js-bottom-sheet": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-space": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-loading-dots": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-material-bottom-navigation": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^0.6.3",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-modalize": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-modern-datepicker": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-motion": "^1.0.4",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.32",
    "react-native-orientation-loading-overlay": "^0.1.6",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-pose": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-pushe": "^1.6.3",
    "react-native-rating-star": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.13",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view-rtl": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-simple-animations": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-simple-dialogs": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.0",
    "react-native-spinkit": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-star-view": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-tecnovix-material-textfield": "^0.18.0",
    "react-native-upload-multiple-images": "^1.0.6-rc",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.12.1",
    "react-navigation-transitions": "^1.0.12",
    "rn-persian-date-picker": "^1.0.6",
    "rn-progress-loader": "^1.0.8",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.4.2",
    "jest": "23.5.0",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}
```